# Was Goddess kali mentioned in the Vedas

Tags: vedas, kali

Goddess kali is one of the most important Goddesses in Hinduism. She is mentioned a lot in Purans, but is she mentioned in the Vedas also?

Comment: Are you interested in the direct mention of the name "kali"?

Comment: @hanugm yes this well do it